# Facebook SDK for Android null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm following simple tutorial at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ and after I made everything work, I have problems `onCompleted` callback method.

My code looks like this:

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

              // callback after Graph API response with user object
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                  TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                  welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                }
              }
            }).executeAsync();
```

since `executeMeRequestAsync` method from tutorial was deprecated. Everything passes fine, and `user != null` evaluates as true so I come inside of the block, **but** on `user.getName()` I always get `NullPointerException` and I've checked while debugging GraphUser instance, and it was filled with null values. What I might be doing wrong? Can it be some problems with application configuration? I've generated new KeyHash and it's correct, so I don't know what else would be incorrect.

Comment: Hmm...are you sure your `findViewById` method isn't returning null? That would mean that `welcome` would be null, and attempting to run a method on it would throw a NPE.

Comment: How stupid I am, welcome really turns null :\. Thanks a lot and sorry for stupid question.

Comment: No problem; I'm just glad you're trying _some_ validation. It's just incomplete ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` can be thrown if `findViewById(R.id.welcome)` returns null. You can modify your logic to check for welcome as well:

```
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);

    if(user != null && welcome != null) {
        welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
    }
    else {
        // Log it in some way
    }
}
```